# Can I Use Google ML Kit for translation for my web app?

Tags: translation, google-translate, google-mlkit

I wan to know if there is a way, to use [Google's ML Kit for Translation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/language/translation), to build translate API's for my web app. I am paying to use Google Translate API's now. Looking for a work around.

Comment: I think you must pay if you want to use the Google API. Are you looking for a paid or free service?

Answer (score 1):

ML Kit does not support web apps today, it is designed for use in native Android and iOS apps. The recommended path for web apps that need translation between languages is indeed to use [Google Cloud Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate).